# force XSS after bypassing Request.Form using URL Encoding

Tags: xss, javascript, encoding

I am testing a cross-site scripting attack on a website, as we all know the `Request.Form` function validates the input so the user couldn't insert a `<script>` inside the input.

My focus in this question isn't how to bypass the `Request.Form`, I am asking how to force the XSS without receiving an error from the server.

I was trying to encode the `<script>alert('xss');</script>` by encoding a text (ASCII text) to Hex values. By encoding to hex values, I tried testing this `%3C%68%31%3E%74%65%73%74%3C%2F%68%31%3E` value, I received an alert error saying:

> There was an error in loading json data.

[image: XSS Error After Encoding]

On the other side, after encoding using HTML with semicolons example: `&#x3C;&#x68;&#x31;&#x3E;&#x74;&#x65;&#x73;&#x74;&#x3C;&#x2F;&#x68;&#x31;&#x3E;` and injecting it in the input, I received again a Request.Form error:
[image: Request.Form Error]

I found on this forum an old post for bypassing the `Request.Form`, but I want to force the XSS without receiving an error.

([How to bypass .Net 4.5 request validation, for an XSS attack?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80089/how-to-bypass-net-4-5-request-validation-for-an-xss-attack))

Comment: Without more context it is not possible to answer. What I find more worrying than any XSS though is the ability to cause hard server errors based on invalid input (the second one, the first one was handled by the application).